# Scraping different values (cookies?) under the same url

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, scrapy

I am using scrapy and beautifulsoup in order to scrape a list of all the hotels in different cities in the US.

When I get to a page called "Hotels in San Francisco" it contains only 30 hotels out of the 250 in the city. Clicking on "next 30 on the list" **doesn't change the url** and neither does changing the sorting parameter.
My question: how can I reach the entire list of 250 hotels, or choose what ranking to scrape from.  Thanks.

My code so far:

```
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
headers = soup.find_all("h1",{"class":"X"})

for header in headers:
    headerText = header.text
    match=re.search('(.+ Hotels)',headerText)
    if match:
        writeHotels(soup,match.group(0))



def writeHotels(soup,location):

   #create Hotels directory
   hotelDir = 'Hotels/'
   if not os.path.exists(hotelDir):
       os.makedirs(hotelDir)


   hotels = soup.find_all("a",{"class":"Y"})
   name=location+'.txt'
   #write hotels to file
   if os.path.exists(hotelDir+name):
       print 'opening file '+name+"\n"
   else:
       print 'creating file '+name+"\n"
   file=open(hotelDir+name,'a') 
   for hotel in hotels:
       file.write(hotel.text+"\n")
   file.close()
```

Comment: can you post the url?

Comment: this totally depends on the page itself, you'll need to use something like chrome develepor tools, or firebug to check which requests are being done.

Comment: http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g60713-San_Francisco_California-Hotels.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the page source at the page numbers on the bottom of the page they have a unique url to each of the pages.  If you print out the soup you see that you can grab that url.  If there are a lot of pages it won't show all of the pages, just a ... for the intermediate pages.  However you can calculate the urls from the first and last values (I did not do that below).  Here is the code I used:

```
url = "http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g60713-San_Francisco_California-Hotels.html" 
page=urllib.request.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
#print(soup)
for myValue3 in soup.findAll("a",attrs={ "class" : "pageNum" }):
    try:
        print("the value of page " + myValue3.get("data-page-number") + " is: " + myValue3.get("href").split("#ACCOM_OVERVIEW")[0])
    except:
        print("error")
```

Here is the output

```
the value of page 2 is: /Hotels-g60713-oa30-San_Francisco_California-Hotels.html
the value of page 3 is: /Hotels-g60713-oa60-San_Francisco_California-Hotels.html
the value of page 4 is: /Hotels-g60713-oa90-San_Francisco_California-Hotels.html
the value of page 5 is: /Hotels-g60713-oa120-San_Francisco_California-Hotels.html
the value of page 6 is: /Hotels-g60713-oa150-San_Francisco_California-Hotels.html
the value of page 8 is: /Hotels-g60713-oa210-San_Francisco_California-Hotels.html
```

notice the `-oa###-` in the url.  That can be changed and you can get all the subsequent pages.

Comment: If the pages has unique urls can I expect the crawl spider to eventually reach them on his own?
Is there a particular crawler Rule that makes the spider reach these pages?

Comment: Sorry, that is a scrapy question and I have not used that tool.  For beautiful soup I would do a `page.read()` and open each one of the pages that you pulled the url of.